# Arduino ACI lib breaks SPI

Tags: arduino, spi

I have a project requiring a bluetooth chip (nrf8001) and an SPI flash memory module.

Prior to calling lib_aci_init, I can read and write the flash memory. After init, I cannot. Is there any reason the ACI lib would be disabling SPI for other devices?

Comment: What is `aci_lib_init` and where did you get it?  A Google search for that term finds only this question.

Comment: I know, its frustrating. It came with the Adafruit example code, you can get it here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_nRF8001/blob/master/utility/lib_aci.h. It handles the communication with the bluetooth device, I tell it which slave select, ready and reset pins to use, and it manages the device.

Comment: In that code file, I see `lib_aci_init`, which is probably what you meant to type in this question.

Comment: you are correct, I will fix

Comment: @DavidGrayson I've got a feeling it's these lines causing the issue:
`SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);
SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);
SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);`

Comment: OK.  It would be good to include references to the libraries you are using and some sample code in your question; you shouldn't assume that everyone knows what you are talking about, or that the people who don't know cannot contribute.  I think I figured it out though, and I'll be posting an answer...

Comment: You are quite right, I usually post better formatted questions than that. I look forward to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the SD card and the nrf8001 are both SPI devices, and the two libraries you are using both use the AVR's hardware SPI module to talk to them.

The function `lib_aci_init` calls [`hal_aci_tl_init`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_nRF8001/blob/master/utility/hal_aci_tl.cpp) which sets up the SPI for talking to the nrf8001 and those settings most likely conflict with the settings for the SD card.  Even if they didn't conflict, you would have to use slave-select pins or something like that to avoid a conflict in the hardware.

Comment: Good guess, but I am using slave select - and as I understand it the SPI protocol is set up specifically to allow communication with multiple devices. The line that seems to be causing the issue is `SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);` removing it breaks the bluetooth, keeping it breaks the flash

Comment: Ok, that's a good find.  You can probably make it work if you call `SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);` before any function calls to the aci library, and then change it back to whatever setting it needs to be before calling the SD card library.

Comment: Sadly not, it involves a SPI.begin and paired SPI.end call as well, and something is using SPI that I can't see because when I start adding start/ends around blocks of code that call SPI, it crashes (no error, just freezes). I got it working for the flash module. But no luck on the BT, I'm now working on making the flash module compatible with LSB first.